# javascript recursion to get innerText

Tags: javascript

I want to learn recursion without selectors and I have divs:

```
<div>
 <div>
     <div>car</div>
 </div>
 <div>
     <div>bus</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>train</div>
</div>
```

How can I traverse the DOM without selectors (tagname..etc) in order to pull out innerText of these 3 divs so that I can push them into an array. NOTE, I need to choose divs that don't have any children elements.

I used document.body.childNodes and after that many if statements to check if there are childNodes.
I did it but it was a long line of code.
I see that it can be done with a recursive function so any help would be amazing.

Thank you!

Comment: You can use `Element.children` to get the children, iterate through them, and recurse into them.

Comment: I tried but the problem begins when i try to get elements that only have children elements.

Comment: Show what you tried so we can help you understand what you did wrong.

Comment: Why are elements that only have children a problem? You iterate over the children and recurse into them.

Comment: @Barmar Because I want to use only divs that don't have children.I want only these divs with innerText .  And that confused me.How to just get the string results without selectors.

Comment: `if (el.childElementCount == 0) { // do stuff for divs that don't have children }`

Comment: `else { for (let i = 0; i < el.children.length; i++) { recurse on el.children[i] }`

Comment: Will try, thank you for your answers! @Barmar

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example to get you started:

```js
function getText(node, accumulator) {
  if (node.nodeType === 3) // 3 == text node
    accumulator.push(node.nodeValue)
  else
    for (let child of node.childNodes)
      getText(child, accumulator)
}

//

allTexts = []
getText(document.querySelector('#start'), allTexts)
console.log(allTexts)
```

```html
<div id="start">
  <div>
    <div>car</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>bus</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>train</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfect!
I changed to get image with this function:

function getText(node, results) {
  if ( (node.nodeType === 3) ) // 3 == text node
    results.push(node.nodeValue)
  else if(node.nodeName==='IMG')
    results.push('<img src="'+node.src+'" >');
  else
    for (let child of node.childNodes)
      getText(child, results)
}

Answer (score 0):

Well what you are trying to achieve can be easily done with a one-liner
`rootElement.innerText.split('\n');`

I know what you were looking for was a recursive function but sometimes the simpler answer is the superior.

If you want to start getting to know recursive functions, here is a basic `factorial` algorithm

```
    function factorial(number) {
        if (number === 0) return 1;
        return number * factorial(number - 1);
    }
    console.log(factorial(5));
```

```js
const root = document.getElementById('root');
const myList = root.innerText.split('\n');
console.log(myList);
```

```html
<div id="root">
    <div>
        <div>car</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>bus</div>
        <div>bike</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>taxi</div>
            <div>
                <div>subway</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>train</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am trying out some challenges , and today is my first day of learning recursion. I want to understand the hard part .But thank you for your answer!

Comment: What if it's all on one line of HTML, so there are no newlines?

Comment: @Barmar the algorithm would still work because string.split() would return an array with the length of one

Comment: But it should be a separate result for each DIV.

Comment: Dear, Yes, I did the factorial example but got confused with element.children and element.childnodes. I was looping through them and I got the result now I just need to figure out the easy way. Thank you!